# Exploring an image (.jpg) file having 2 pages of a text Book and extract the text to save in .txt file (both files in local folder)

Tags: python, image-processing, computer-vision

I am using Ms Azure Credentials for **Computer Vision** to access an image file and extract the text from it and finally to save it in .txt file. The codes are working fine with url having .jpg extension. My codes are giving some errors with

1. image files with .jpg extension saved in local folder.
2. image files from web with url which do. not have .jpg extension.

My codes are here-in-under

```
    '''url of the remote (web) Image File'''
#remote_image_url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-sample-data-files/master/ComputerVision/Images/landmark.jpg"
#imagefile = "<filepath>//IMAGE1.JPG"
remote_image_url = "http://site.meishij.net/r/58/25/3568808/a3568808_142682562777944.jpg"

    ## Saving a url image to local folder as jpg
import requests
pic_url = "http://site.meishij.net/r/58/25/3568808/a3568808_142682562777944.jpg"
#pic_url = "https://wallup.net/new-york-city-manhattan-nyc-usa-new-york-manhattan-usa-city-type-height-panorama-night-pink-sunset-blue-sky-clouds-lights-light-house-building-skyscraper-skyscrapers-5/"
with open('C://Users//ubana//OneDrive//ANIL JOSHI//PROJECTS//CONVERSION TO TXT FILE//IMAGES//pic1.jpg', 'wb') as handle:
        response = requests.get(pic_url, stream=True)

        if not response.ok:
            print (response)

        for block in response.iter_content(1024):
            if not block:
                break

            handle.write(block)

    '''
Describe an Image - remote
This example describes the contents of an image with the confidence score.
'''
print("===== Describe an image - remote =====")
# Call API
description_results = computervision_client.describe_image(remote_image_url)

# Get the captions (descriptions) from the response, with confidence level
print("Description of remote image: ")
if (len(description_results.captions) == 0):
    print("No description detected.")
else:
    for caption in description_results.captions:
        print("'{}' with confidence {:.2f}%".format(caption.text, caption.confidence * 100))
```

The errors are following

**ComputerVisionErrorException              Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
5 print("===== Describe an image - remote =====")
6 # Call API
----> 7 description_results = computervision_client.describe_image(imgfile)
8
9 # Get the captions (descriptions) from the response, with confidence level
~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\azure\cognitiveservices\vision\computervision\operations_computer_vision_client_operations.py in describe_image(self, url, max_candidates, language, description_exclude, custom_headers, raw, **operation_config)
201
202         if response.status_code not in [200]:
--> 203             raise models.ComputerVisionErrorException(self._deserialize, response)
204
205         deserialized = None
ComputerVisionErrorException: Image URL is badly formatted.**

I appreciate if anyone help me on this issuer

Salil Ray

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there is an error with the file path in

```
with open('C://Users//ubana//OneDrive//ANIL JOSHI//PROJECTS//CONVERSION TO TXT FILE//IMAGES//pic1.jpg', 'wb') as handle:
```

is incorrect. Maybe try using double backslashes rather than forward slashes in the file path, like this:

```
with open('C:\\Users\\ubana\\OneDrive\\ANIL JOSHI\\PROJECTS\\CONVERSION TO TXT FILE\\IMAGES\\pic1.jpg', 'wb') as handle:
```